# Why isn't Postgres prompting for password when using psql?

Tags: postgresql

Given the following pg_hba.conf, why isn't Postgres prompting for a password when running `psql -h localhost -p 5555 --username=mydb`?

```
local postgres postgres trust
local mydb mydb md5
local mydb mydb password
host mydb mydb 0.0.0.0/0 password
host mydb mydb 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Comment: is there a `.pgpass` file in the home directory?

Comment: @ewcz Yes, that was it. Please add your comment as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html) states:

> The file .pgpass in a user's home directory or the file referenced by PGPASSFILE can contain passwords to be used if the connection requires a password (and no password has been specified otherwise).